# Why does my code in setTimeout not work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, call

My method, `Chomp.prototype.animate` does not work properly. My code works when the function does not apply `Chomp.prototype.playerMove`.

When `Chomp.prototype.playerMove` is applied, then the if statement involving `counter` before the addEventListener can sometimes execute the addEventListener, even if  `counter` is greater than one, those times it executes the function in addEventListener many times, depending on how long the code was running before it was executed. Those times, it should not have executed the addEventListener, and if it did, then counter should be added to more than one, and then not executed again. Counter was added to more than one, even on these times of the addEventListener being executed multiple times.

Even stranger, when I have `Chomp.prototype.animate` always set `counter` to 1 instead of 0, it will still execute the if statement that says `if (counter < 1)` once. Also, when `Chomp.prototype.playerMove` is applied, then `Chomp.prototype.chomping` does not work quite right. (It does work without `Chomp.prototype.playerMove`). This is very strange, and I do not understand the problem.

If there is request for a certain part of my code, then I could post that, but my full code is probably not all useful to the question.

```
var counter = 0;
var rotation;
var Chomp = function(x, y) {
  /*many properties*/
}
Chomp.prototype.chomping = function() {
  /*properties and conditions, etc.*/
}
Chomp.prototype.animate = function() {
  var that = this;
  Chomp.prototype.chomping.apply(this);
  Chomp.prototype.playerMove.apply(this);
  //counter = 1;
  counter = 0;
  setTimeout(function(){
    Chomp.prototype.animate.apply(that);
  }, 100);
}
Chomp.prototype.playerMove = function() {
  var that = this;
  /*values*/
  var yNew = 0, xNew = 0, rotate = "";
  var once = function(event) {
    /*conditions for keys, etc.*/
    Chomp.prototype.move.call(that, xNew, yNew, rotate);
    /*values*/
    removeEventListener("keydown", once);
  }
  if (counter < 1)
    addEventListener("keydown", once); 
  /*more code*/
  }
Chomp.prototype.move = function(xNew, yNew, rotate) {
  var that = this;
  counter += 1;
  /*loops, conditions, etc.*/
var yellow = new Chomp(30, 60);
Chomp.prototype.animate.apply(yellow);
```

Thanks ahead of time! :)

Comment: I run my code in http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/, if it makes a difference, but probably not.

Comment: Why are you calling `Chomp.prototype.animate.apply(yellow)` instead of `yellow.animate()`? The same with `Chomp.prototype.chomping.apply(this)` should be `this.chomping()`, etc.

Comment: @RobG, I need to have `yellow` be the this of `Chomp.prototype.animate`, maybe they would both work? It does work for when I do not have `Chomp.prototype.playerMove` applied, so therefore it must not be the problem.

Comment: @RobG, both do have the same effect, and so it is not the problem, I have tested it. Thanks for suggesting, though.

Comment: That's how inheritance is supposed to work. A function's *this* is set by the call, so when you do `yellow.animate()` then *this* within *animate* will be *yellow* (until ES6 arrow functions come along with a kind of implicit *bind*…).

Comment: I suspect your issue is that you are attaching multiple instances of *once*, since each time *animate* is called a new instance is created. So when you remove one, there are still others left behind. Move the function creation to outside the prototype (e.g. make it global and use a function declaration, not an expression). That will at least test the theory. Once you've done that, you can work on how to make it not global but once only. :-)

Comment: @RobG, that did not work, but that does not disprove your theory. I did need to change the function once so that inside the method under the counter, I had `addEventListener("keydown", once.bind(that));`. In removing the event listener, then I tried both `("keydown", once)` and `("keydown", once.bind(that)` inside once, neither worked properly. I also had to declare at the top of once that `var that = this;` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the `yellow` context when invoking `Chomp.prototype.animate`. `yellow`, which is an instance of `Chomp`, will be bound to `this` when you are inside of the `Chomp.prototype.animate` declaration, which means that all of your bindings to `this` are now bound to the Chomp instance `yellow`, and not the `Chomp.prototype` object. I am not really sure why you are using `Chomp.prototype` to invoke all of your methods within the prototype methods if you are planning on using them with instances of `Chomp` and not `Chomp.prototype` (they are two different objects!). It might make more sense to use `this` within all of your `Chomp.prototype` methods.

It would be necessary to see the rest of the code because your prototype is creating a ton of side effects within the other methods for which you are just showing `/* etc... */`, and I am not sure what logic those side effects are triggering within your program... Post more code or PM me and we can work on a refactor together to avoid these problems in the first place. Cheers

p.s. wanted to post this as a comment but it is too long